# How to determine the "polarisation" of the magnetic field caused by magnetic induction?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the idea of magnetic induction caused by the current flow in a wire.

- Considering that the magnetic field created by current flow is circular in its very nature, how do we determine its polarization?

Since according to Lenz's law, when a magnet consisting of a north and south pole approaches a coil, the induced current creates a magnetic field which is supposed to oppose the field which induced the current, which means that if I approach a magnet which a north pole pointing to the coil, the created magnetic field should act as a magnet with a north pole pointing towards magnet's north pole as well in order to push it away. But regardless of the current flow, it's still impossible to say (at least for me, hence the question) how the polarization is set, given that the field takes the form of a circle with no beginning nor end.

I'll be extremely grateful for some enlightening explanations or links to resources which can explain it in a digestible manner.